# C# Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I am trying to copy values from an IList collection(Entities here) to stringbuilder as

```
Entites.Select(n => objStringBuilder.AppendLine(n.Note));
```

Can anyone please guide what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell, what goes wrong?

Comment: That should work, although you should really use ForEach instead of Select as you are not actually selecting anything. No big deal though. If it is not actually working, what error message are you getting? Having a problem with "n.Note"?

Comment: Also, you have spelt Entities wrong: "Entites". It's not a syntax error is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select` is not what you want to use you here.  Try casting to a `List<T>` and using `ForEach` instead.

```
Entities.ToList().ForEach(n => objStringBuilder.AppendLine(n.Note));
```

Comment: But the strange thing is the original code using Select works. StringBuilder AppendLine returns a StringBuilder, so Select will work with it.

Comment: I think I should downvote the OP, but your answer is not good if the entities are really entity objects, this causes to load all data from server, It's better do one select to retrieve strings and then fill it in loop or use ToList and ForEach. (Also other answers are bad in this case)

Answer (score 6):

That looks more like a foreach operation. i'd stick with the traditional for each in this case:

```
foreach (var n in Entities) { 
    objStringBuilder.AppendLine(n.Note);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Join("", entities.Select(x => x.Note).ToArray())
```

or if you insist on StringBuilder:

```
Entities.Foreach(x => sb.Append(x.Note))
```

(The Select expects that you provide a returned value)

Comment: AppendLine returns a StringBuilder, so the OPs original Select code does actually work in this case.

Comment: The `.ToArray()` isn't necessary in .net 4 anymore since `String.Join` has an overload for `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: @fejesco Saeed is correct - ForEach exists on List<T>, not IList<T> - it is not an extension method either. Please try and at least compile your code before getting the hump with people who comment on it.

Comment: @fejesjoco, I think you are only person in a world aware of this! you should insert your code for extension method and extension class, where is ForEach? Also I didn't downvoted you, because I'd downvoted 3 people before reading your answer, another one downvoted you. It's better remove your answer like others.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that we have a framework that provides an IEnumerable ForEach, it's one of those convenience things that Microsoft strangely left out. So it actually compiles for me. But you're right, it doesn't help OP, but the ToArray method does. Now, feel free to downvote :)

Comment: @fejesjoco, Microsoft people are intelligence enough, they didn't do this because of differed execution, read about it in internet :)

Comment: In our framework it's not deferred, it's just a void function: void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> l, Action<T> a) { foreach (var e in l) a(e); } I've gotten so used to this one that I totally forgot it's not BCL, so shame's on me.

Comment: foreach (var e in l) ... causes to all data to be read, so if it's an entity context object it's very bad, read about yield pattern and differed execution (It's not what you think), in linq when you writing a query it's not going to be done, until you want fetch data, so if you have Where().Where()... it will check all constrains and when you run foreach or similar thing it will be fetched.

Comment: Okay, to begin with, what is differed execution? You're right, I don't know what that is. I know about deferred execution, it means that Where, Select and others return iterators, not lists. In these cases, the C# compiler generates enumerator classes which run the code in the MoveNext function. About my ForEeach: it's not deferred because it doesn't return an iterator. And this is actually what I want: when I want to do something for all elements of an enumeration, then deferring makes no sense. Just like ToArray, it's the last step of an iteration, the result of which you need immediately.